# finding duplicates in a field and printing them in unix bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file the contains

```
apple
apple
banana
orange
apple
orange
```

I want a script that finds the duplicates apple and orange and tells the user that the following : apple and orange are repeated.
I tried

```
nawk '!x[$1]++' FS="," filename
```

to find repeated item
so how can i print them out in unix bash ?

Answer (score 11):

In order to print the duplicate lines, you can say:

```
$ sort filename | uniq -d
apple
orange
```

If you want to print the count as well, supply the `-c` option to `uniq`:

```
$ sort filename | uniq -dc
      3 apple
      2 orange
```

Comment: Note that according to uniq, word "ウェイター" is duplicate of "ウエイター" (ェ=エ)

Answer (score 4):

+1 for [devnul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17917666/1066031). However, if the file contains spaces instead of newlines as delimiter. then the following would work.

```
tr [:blank:] "\n" < filename | sort | uniq -d
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

The question has been changed significantly. Formerly, when answering this, the input file should look like:

```
apple apple banana orange apple orange
banana orange apple
...
```

However, the solution will work anyway, but might be a little bit too complicated for this special use case.

---

The following awk script will do the job:

```
awk '{i=1;while(i <= NF){a[$(i++)]++}}END{for(i in a){if(a[i]>1){print i,a[i]}}}' your.file
```

Output:

```
apple 3
orange 2
```

It is more understandable in a form like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

{
  i=1;
  # iterate through every field
  while(i <= NF) {
    a[$(i++)]++; # count occurrences of every field
  }
}

# after all input lines have been read ...
END {
  for(i in a) {
    # ... print those fields which occurred more than 1 time
    if(a[i] > 1) {
      print i,a[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Then make the file executable and execute it passing the input file name to it:

```
chmod +x script.awk
./script.awk your.file
```

Comment: +1.  On attempting to format the question, it became evident that the input file had items placed on different lines.  I agree that it was hard to *guess* that.

Comment: @devnull :) I guessed something like this.. however, now we have two solutions for two slightly different use cases. as a result, this is not so bad.....

Comment: what if there are 2 fields ? and how does it know if which file it should search ?

Comment: @user2613272 Scroll to the above code field to the right.. You'll need to give the file name as an argument.. It should work with two fields.. doesn't it?